# Why is overflow error in two's complement addition represented by XOR-ing the last two carries?

Tags: computers, computer-arithmetic

The first chapter of my textbook on microcontroller theory has the following paragraph.

[image]

Here is one of the examples provided.
[image]

The book shows three such examples, but provides no explanation for why this is true in general. Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: One slightly non intuitive case is when both numbers are negative, then \$c_p = 1\$ otherwise there will be overflow (actually underflow).

Answer (score 1):

Overflow can **only** occur if the two numbers have the same sign. If it has occurred then the result will have the opposite sign.

Consider the following 8 possibilities where A & B represent the MSB of the number (sign) and S is the sum sign.

A B Cp   S  Cf  Overflow?

0 0 0    0  0

0 0 1    1  0  **Y**

0 1 0    1  0

0 1 1    0  1

1 0 0    1  0

1 0 1    0  1

1 1 0    0  1   **Y**

1 1 1    1  1

So overflow has occurred iff Cp⊕Cf = 1